# add text to end of array items depending on the item number

Tags: javascript

I've got a dropdown list of numbers which I intend to use to track my miles. I want to add the text 'miles' after the number but if the number is 1, I want to add 'mile'.

unit = miles |
arrayOfArrays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Here is my script

```
function showQtyNumbers(el, arrayOfArrays, unit) {
    alert(arrayOfArrays);
    el.innerHTML = '';
    arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', r);
        option.text = r + ' ' + unit;
        el.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
```

That gives me the results: 0 miles, 1 miles, 2 miles etc.

I've tried the following but it does not work.

```
function showQtyNumbers(el, arrayOfArrays, unit) {
    number1 = arrayOfArrays.find(e => e === 1)
    el.innerHTML = '';
    arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        if (r.find(e => e === 1)) {
          r + unit.substring(0, unit.length - 1)
        } else {
           option.text = r + unit; 
        };
        option.setAttribute('value', r);
       
        
        el.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
```

I Know `arrayOfArrays.find(e => e === 1)` finds 1 but I don't know how to do it in forEach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pass the value for unit to the function as singular and append an 's' if the value is not 1?  Like this:

```
 if(r!=1){ option.text = r + unit +"s"; }else{ option.text = r + unit; }
```

Comment: So simple, I'm new and sometime I overthink things.

Comment: It happens :) Look for the logic always.